# responsiveness of my website screws up on 5SE and Galaxy Fold

Tags: html, css

I'm getting this issue where a part of my website screws up, I don't know how to properly explain it but filler content/white space starts horizontally getting place as you can see in this image here

[image]

When I actually want it to be like this [image]

I dont know what to show because my CSS file is like 900 lines long but I tried doing width: 100%;

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


:root {
    --clr-text: white;
    --clr-secondary-text: yellow;
    --clr-primary: #098ef6;
    --clr-background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    --border-color: white;
    --clr-bg-border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    
    --ff-primary: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    --ff-global: 'Staatliches', cursive;
    
}

html {
    font-family: var(--ff-global);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../images3/test.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
    /* OUTLINE COLOR */
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black;
    min-height: 100vh;
    
}

button {
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black;
    font-family: var(--ff-global)
}




/* Screen Loader */

.background-loading {
    background-color: var(--clr-primary);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper{
    width:200px;
    height:60px;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    left:15%;
    transform-origin: 50%;
    animation: circle .5s alternate infinite ease;
}

@keyframes circle{
    0%{
        top:60px;
        height:5px;
        border-radius: 50px 50px 25px 25px;
        transform: scaleX(1.7);
    }
    40%{
        height:20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    100%{
        top:0%;
    }
}
.circle:nth-child(2){
    left:45%;
    animation-delay: .2s;
}
.circle:nth-child(3){
    left:auto;
    right:15%;
    animation-delay: .3s;
}
.shadow{
    width:20px;
    height:4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
    top:62px;
    transform-origin: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    left:15%;
    filter: blur(1px);
    animation: shadow .5s alternate infinite ease;
}

@keyframes shadow{
    0%{
        transform: scaleX(1.5);
    }
    40%{
        transform: scaleX(1);
        opacity: .7;
    }
    100%{
        transform: scaleX(.2);
        opacity: .4;
    }
}
.shadow:nth-child(4){
    left: 45%;
    animation-delay: .2s
}
.shadow:nth-child(5){
    left:auto;
    right:15%;
    animation-delay: .3s;
}
.wrapper h1{
    position: absolute;
    top:75px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    left:15%;
}




/* Header Section */

.promotion-header {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: var(--clr-text);
}

.header-section {
    background-color: var(--clr-primary);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    position: sticky;
}


.header-logo {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.nav-links {
}


.nav-links ul {
}

.nav-links li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    text-decoration: none
}

.nav-links a:hover {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    transition: ease 650ms;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    margin-left: auto;
    order: 2;
    padding-right: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.hamburger-menu-info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    background-color: var(--clr-primary);
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    transition: ease 1ms;
    z-index: 999;
    position: sticky;
    top: 2.6em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.hamburger-menu-info ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.hamburger-menu-info li {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger-menu-info a {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger-menu-info a:hover {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    transition: ease 650ms;
}

.hamburger-menu-close {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    margin-left: auto;
    order: 2;
    padding-right: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
    



/* Footer Section */

footer {
    /*border-top: 3px solid var(--border-color);*/
    
    background-color: var(--clr-primary); 
}


.footer {
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
}

.footer-col {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    
}

.footer-col a {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-col a:hover {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    transition: ease 650ms;
}

.footer-col ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-col h1 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.footer-col h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* Home Page Styling */

/* Banner Section */

.banner-section {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 50vh;
}

.banner-section h1 {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Services Section */

.services-section {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    
}

.services-section a {
    
}

.services-section h1 {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
    
}

.services-section h2 {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
    
}

.title-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2em;
}

.services {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    margin-top: 1em;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .services {  
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        display: grid;
        gap: 10px;
        margin-top: 1em;
        justify-items: center;
    
    }
}   

.service-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 20vh;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width: 30vh;
}

.service-container {
    border: 5px solid var(--clr-primary);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: black;
    min-height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 30vh;
}

.service-container i {
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: right;
}

.service-container h1 {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.service-container h2 {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.service-container h1:hover {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    transition: ease 650ms;
}

.service-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
}

.service-button a {
    background-color: var(--clr-primary);
    color: var(--clr-text);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    
}

.service-button a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 white, 1px -1px 0 white, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white;
    transition: ease 650ms;
}

.service-about {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    height: fixed;
    width: fixed;
}

.service-about p {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.service-about span {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.service-about a {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.featured-services {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
    justify-items: center;
}

/* TABLE STYLING */

.service-table {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.service-table table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.service-table th {
    background-color: var(--clr-primary);
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
.service-table td {
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.service-table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}


/* CANVAS PAGE */

.canvas-about {
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    
}

.canvas-about a {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.canvas-table-links {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    width: fixed;
    height: fixed;
}

.canvas-link {
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    width: fixed;
    height: fixed;
    padding: .5em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 1em;

}

.canvas-link a {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black;
}

.canvas-link h1 {
    font-weight: normal;

}
.canvas-link a:hover {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    transition: ease 650ms;
}

/* About Us */

.about-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 1em;
    
}

.about-bg {
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
}

.about-text {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.about-img {
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.about-img img {
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    width: 100%;
    height: fixed;
}

/* Login Page */

.footer-fix {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
    

.login-background {
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    padding: 1em;
    height: fixed;
    width: fixed;
}

.login-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--clr-text);
    
}

.login-content h1:hover {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    transition: ease 650ms;
}

.login-content h1 {
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    padding-top: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.login-content a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--clr-text);
}

.login-content h2 {
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    padding-top: 1em;
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-weight: normal;
}


.login-content img {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.margin-shift {
    margin: 1em;
}

input[type=text], [type=password] {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 3px solid var(--clr-text);
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: var(--clr-text);
    padding: 0.5em;
}

input[type=text]:focus, [type=password]:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 3px solid var(--clr-text);
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: var(--clr-text);
    padding: 0.5em;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    border: 3px solid var(--clr-secondary-text);
    transition: ease 650ms;
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    cursor: pointer;
}

input::placeholder {
    color: var(--clr-text);
}

input {
    font-family: var(--ff-global);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
}


/* Contact Us */

.contact-us {
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);

}

.contact-icon {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.contact-icon i {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 0.3em;
}

.contact-info {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    
    text-align: center;
}


.contact-info h1, h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.contact-info h2 {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
}


/* FAQ */

.faq-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 1em;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.faq-question {
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    color: var(--clr-text);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.faq-question h1, h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.faq-answer {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    padding: 0.5em;
}



/* Admin Page */

.admin-section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.adminpage-background {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    height: fixed;
    margin-top: 1em;
    width: 75%;
}

.adminpage-background input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 5vh;
    height: 5vw;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    
}

.adminpage-background input {
    padding: 1em;
}

.adminpage-background h1 {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.adminpage-forms {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    height: fixed;
    margin-top: 1em;
    width: 75%;
}

.adminpage-forms h2 {
    color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    font-weight: normal;
}



/* SLIDER */

.slider {
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
    clip-path: circle(0.0% at 50% 47%);
}

.slider .slide.active {
    clip-path: circle(70.7% at 50% 50%);
    transition: ease 1s;
}

.slider .slide img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.navigation {
    height: 40vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.prev-btn, .next-btn {
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 4em;
    color: var(--clr-text);
    background: var(--clr-primary);
    padding: .1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

/* Product Container */

.product-container {
    border: 5px solid var(--clr-primary);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: black;
    min-height: 20vh;
    min-width: 30vh;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.product-container h1 {
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.products {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
    justify-items: center;
}

/* PROMOTION PAGE */

.promotions {
    display: grid;
    color: var(--clr-text);
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
    text-align: center;
    justify-items: center;
}

.promotion-container {
    border: 5px solid var(--clr-primary);
    min-height: 20vh;
    min-width: 30vh;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.promotion-text h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.promotion-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1em;
}

.promotion-button button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.promotion-button button:hover {
    background-color: var(--clr-secondary-text);
    color: black;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 white, 1px -1px 0 white, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white;
    transition: ease 650ms;
}

.promotion-button button {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    background-color: var(--clr-primary);
    font-size: 1.15rem;
}

.canvas-page {
    padding: 2em;
}


/* ABOUT US PAGE */

.aboutUs-section {
    padding: 2em;
}

.information-text {
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
}

.information-image img {
    height: 30vh;
    width: 40vh;
    border: var(--clr-bg-border);
}

.information-image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Here is my code for CSS if you'd like to see

Here is HTML code too for the about page

```
<?php include ('header.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>

<title>About Us</title>
<div class="banner-section" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(images3/heroImage.jpg);">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
</div>

<!--
<div class="about-section">
    <div class="about-bg">
        <div class="about-text">
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="about-img">
            <img src="images3/heroImage.jpg" alt="About Image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

-->

<div class="aboutUs-section">
    <div class="information-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel ante quis erat semper sodales vel in velit. Vestibulum in mauris at lorem maximus vulputate quis id neque. Suspendisse varius orci eu nisl blandit aliquam. Morbi ante massa, pulvinar et sagittis a, iaculis at ex. Phasellus in nibh tortor. Nunc luctus justo eget consequat volutpat. Maecenas blandit purus vitae mattis lobortis. Donec egestas ultricies turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque sollicitudin neque odio, non imperdiet neque sagittis eget. Aenean pulvinar sodales congue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="information-image">
        <img src="images3/canvas1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="information-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel ante quis erat semper sodales vel in velit. Vestibulum in mauris at lorem maximus vulputate quis id neque. Suspendisse varius orci eu nisl blandit aliquam. Morbi ante massa, pulvinar et sagittis a, iaculis at ex. Phasellus in nibh tortor. Nunc luctus justo eget consequat volutpat. Maecenas blandit purus vitae mattis lobortis. Donec egestas ultricies turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque sollicitudin neque odio, non imperdiet neque sagittis eget. Aenean pulvinar sodales congue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="information-image">
        <img src="images3/canvas1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="information-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel ante quis erat semper sodales vel in velit. Vestibulum in mauris at lorem maximus vulputate quis id neque. Suspendisse varius orci eu nisl blandit aliquam. Morbi ante massa, pulvinar et sagittis a, iaculis at ex. Phasellus in nibh tortor. Nunc luctus justo eget consequat volutpat. Maecenas blandit purus vitae mattis lobortis. Donec egestas ultricies turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque sollicitudin neque odio, non imperdiet neque sagittis eget. Aenean pulvinar sodales congue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="information-image">
        <img src="images3/canvas1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

</div>
<?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
```

Here is the HTML code for the header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="Active Printing" content="Active Printing">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
<meta name="author" content="Brady Smith">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css3/newCSS3.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">


<?php
    
    require_once 'includes/dbh-inc.php';
    $sql = "SELECT clientName, startDate, endDate FROM Clients";
    $result = $conn-> query($sql);
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate));
    $promotion;
    if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            if (($currentDate >= $row["startDate"]) && ($currentDate <= $row["endDate"])){
                $promotion = true;
                
                
            }
            
        }
        if ($promotion === true) {
                echo '<div class="promotion-header">';
                echo '<h1>Promotion on-going!</h1>';
                echo '</div>';
        }
    }
?>



<div class="header-section">


    <div class="header-logo">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="images3/logo.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactUs.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="promotions.php">Promotions</a></li>
            <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) {
                    
                    if(time()-$_SESSION["login_time_stamp"] >1800) 
                    {
                        session_unset();
                        session_destroy();
                    }
                    
                    #echo '<li><a href="shoppingCart.php">Shopping Cart</a></li>';
                    echo '<li><a href="includes/logout.inc.php">Log out</a></li>';
                    
                }
                
                else if (isset($_SESSION["adminuid"])) {
                    
                    if(time()-$_SESSION["login_time_stamp"] >1800) 
                    {
                        session_unset();
                        session_destroy();
                    }
                    
                    
                    echo '<li><a href="adminPage.php">Admin Page</a></li>';
                    echo '<li><a href="includes/logout.inc.php">Log out</a></li>';
                    
                    
                }
                
                else {
                    echo '<li><a href="loginPage.php">Login</a></li>';
                }
            
            
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <i class="fas fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hamburger-menu-close">
        <i class="fas fa-times fa-3x"></i>
    </div>


</div>

    <div class="hamburger-menu-info">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactUs.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="promotions.php">Promotions</a></li>
            <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) {
                    #echo '<li><a href="shoppingCart.php">Shopping Cart</a></li>';
                    echo '<li><a href="includes/logout.inc.php">Log out</a></li>';
                }
            
                else if (isset($_SESSION["adminuid"])) {
                    echo '<li><a href="adminPage.php">Admin Page</a></li>';
                    echo '<li><a href="includes/logout.inc.php">Log out</a></li>';
                }
                
                else {
                    echo '<li><a href="loginPage.php">Login</a></li>';
                }
            
            
            ?>
        </ul>
    
    </div>

<style>
    @media (max-width: 1600px) {
        .nav-links {
            display: none;
        }
        .hamburger-menu {
            display: block;
            visibility: visible;
        }
        
        .hamburger-menu-info {
            display: none;
        }

    }

</style>


<script src="javascript3/headerScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check any margins or padding in your body or the container of the filler content. If nothing Is working and you really need to make it more width, than try 110% width or some other width when the browser width is less than 375px or something. We cannot really help you with an image unless you give us some code, but those are some of my thoughts.

Comment: @JohnDoe I decided to put my CSS code in to see if that would help, I added width: 100% and it seemed to screw up a lot of my code.

Comment: Maybe if I could see all of the code. Perhaps make a Codepen with the full project? ( the HTML )

Comment: @devsandbox Just added, about us page and header file aswell

Comment: @xSmiiB Your code seems to work as you expect on my end: https://i.imgur.com/NMPcRow.png. I'm using Chrome

Comment: @devsandbox maybe its that close button thats going out more? seems about the same size of the whitespace its making

Comment: @xSmiiB yeah it seems to work on Safari as well

Comment: Hey there, getting the same problem. Were you able to solve it?